# Nodal Analysis - Finding voltage given the network

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image: Practice Problem]

My attempt to solve:

I = 10A
i1 = ??
i2 = ??
i3 = ??
ix = ??

Using KCL 
@Node 1: I = i1 + i2 
@Node 2: i2 + 4ix = ix 
@Node 3: i1 = i3 + 4ix

Applying current definitionsf

10 = (v1 - v3)/2 + (v1 - v2)/4 (1)
(v1 - v2)/3 + 4(v2 - 0)/4 = (v2 - 0)/4 (2)
(v1 - v3)/2 = (v3 - 0)/6 + 4(v2 - 0)/4 (3)

Applying cross multiplication

40 = 2(v1 - v3) + (v1 - v2) (1)
4(v1 - v2) + 4v2 = v2  (2)
6(v1 - v3) - 2v3 = 4v2   (3)

Cleaning things up a bit

3v1 - v2 - 2v3 = 40
4v1 - v2            = 0
6v1 - 4v2 - 8v3 = 0

Using a calculator to solve:

v1 = 26.67 V
v2 = 16.67 V
v3 = -33.33 V

My answer was far from being correct. Any help?

Comment: i1 traverses the 2Ω resistor, entering node 3. There is also a dependent current source 4ix leaving the node 3. Then I made i3 leaving the node 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your first equation for current. It is wrong in the RHS. It should be:

$$ 10 = (V_1 - V_3)/2 + ( V_1 - V_2)/3  $$

Answer (score 1):

I wish you'd used the schematic editor. Then I'd have labels for everything. I'm not going to waste time adding such a schematic. (But I get that you also included some text and an answer in your picture.) So just examine the following using nodal analysis, assuming the bottom node is ground or \$0\:\text{V}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_1}{3\:\Omega}+\frac{V_1}{2\:\Omega}&=10\:\text{A}+\frac{V_2}{3\:\Omega}+\frac{V_3}{2\:\Omega}\tag{Node 1}\\\\
\frac{V_2}{3\:\Omega}+\frac{V_2}{4\:\Omega}&=4\cdot I_X+\frac{V_1}{3\:\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{4\:\Omega}\tag{Node 2}\\\\
\frac{V_3}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_3}{6\:\Omega}+4\cdot I_X&=\frac{V_1}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{6\:\Omega}\tag{Node 3}\\\\
I_X&=\frac{V_2}{4\:\Omega}\tag{Compute $I_X$}
\end{align*}$$

Sympy tells me:

```
solve( [
....: Eq(v1/3+v1/2,10+v2/3+v3/2),
....: Eq(v2/3+v2/4,4*ix+v1/3+0/4),
....: Eq(v3/2+v3/6+4*ix,v1/2+0/6),
....: Eq(ix,v2/4) ],
....: [v1,v2,v3,ix] )
{v2: -64, ix: -16, v1: 80, v3: 156}
```

Does that help?

Here is how I developed the above equations:

> ---
>
> Equation rules:
>
> - Keep all outgoing currents on the left side
> - Keep all incoming currents on the right side
> - If not already chosen by the problem, pick a convenient node and call
>     it "ground." This allows you to assign \$0\:\text{V}\$ to that node and
>     this will simplify some of the equations. Which node to select is up to
>     you. But I will pick one that either helps make the schematic easier to
>     understand, or else will simplify the equations more than other choices.
>
> I like to imagine a 3D chessboard -- those funny chessboards with tiny
>   sub-chessboard areas that sit at different heights. Each node in the
>   circuit is represented as one of these sub-areas (or "platforms"), sitting at some unknown
>   elevation and held there on a long pole beneath it. This unknown elevation
>   is the voltage you must find. One of these can be placed at "0 height." But
>   that's just arbitrary, since then there still may be platforms above and/or
>   below. So it's just a way of conveniently locating the "ground floor," so
>   to speak.
>
> I treat the currents as water. Water flows onto and off of each platform.
>   The left side of the equation, the outgoing currents, is represented by the
>   water that is flowing off of the perimeter of the platform. The right side
>   of the equation, the incoming currents, is represented by the water that is
>   flowing onto the platform from other platforms above it. The amount of water
>   falling onto such a platform must equal the water flowing off of it via the
>   perimeter edge. (Of course, otherwise water would magically build up on the platform -- or the reverse, get created out of thin air. Both are impossible.)
>
> (No water is ever lost and all of it
>   remains in play and the water cannot accumulate on the floors -- the net
>   flow onto a floor must equal the net flow off of it -- KCL! -- and hence
>   the justification for setting the left side equal to the right side.)
>
> ---

Look at \$N_1\$.

You only have ***two*** paths ***out*** of the node, via the two resistors. So the left side of the equation will have the voltage at the \$N_1\$ *platform* pouring away through these two resistors. That's the two fractions on the left side. You cannot go against a current source. So that is not a path out of the node.

You have ***three*** paths ***into*** the node, via the two resistors (of course, because they work both directions) and then also via the incoming current source. So the right side of the equation will have the current source value plus the two fractions posed by taking the voltage at those nearby platforms (\$N_2\$ and \$N_3\$) divided by their resistor paths into this node.

That's it. That's the first equation.

The rest are done just the same way.

***I was first introduced to this method because that's how the formulas are generated by Spice in source code I examined.*** It took me only a moment to "get the idea" and let it replace all prior instructions I had regarding nodal analysis.

But a very, very good reason is also that the bookkeeping is easier. I'm a lot less likely now to make dumb mistakes. I can't count how many times I got the sign wrong when trying to work out "the voltage on this side minus the voltage on that side" mental gymnastics. This method completely saves me from such troubles. And I can write accurate equations as fast as I can write with a pen or pencil, that I know are right from simple inspection. And that is the final good reason. It's trivial for me to double-check the work, later, without really having to engage my brain much. With the "difference from this side to that side" gymnastics, I still have to do that same gymnastics if I review the equations. And while I may catch errors this next time, there is a far too high possibility that I might again just "agree" with myself over old errors.

All such problems are removed using this method.

And Spice likes it, too.

---

Let me redo the above equations more into your own form:

$$\begin{align*}
10\:\text{A}&=\frac{V_1-V_3}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_1-V_2}{3\:\Omega}\tag{Node 1}\\\\
\frac{V_2-0\:\text{V}}{4\:\Omega}&=\frac{V_1-V_2}{3\:\Omega}+4\cdot \frac{V_2-0\:\text{V}}{4\:\Omega}\tag{Node 2}\\\\
\frac{V_1-V_3}{2\:\Omega}&=4\cdot \frac{V_2-0\:\text{V}}{4\:\Omega}+\frac{V_3-0\:\text{V}}{6\:\Omega}\tag{Node 3}
\end{align*}$$

In this case, I have used your approach. But notice that I came up with different equations.

Please examine the new equations above and compare them with yours.

Comment: Still could not arrive to the answer. Maybe I did something wrong. By the way, I arranged them like (v1 - v3)/2 and etcz

Comment: @JemCelespara I'll try and help a little more. Sorry about being too terse in my answer. I'll try and expand my thinking to see if it helps a little more.

Comment: @JemCelespara Or not. I guess I'm confused. You've selected an answer and also provided your own answer, too. Let me know if there is anything I can do to help. Until then, I'll hold off of trying since I think you must already have an answer... or, not? I can't tell.

Comment: I'll keep on trying. Besides, the one I provided could probably be the correct one. Even authors make mistakes too

Comment: @JemCelespara No, their answers are correct for this case. Have you placed it into Spice? The numbers work out.

Comment: No. I don't have Spice on my laptop. Is it free? Or at least available for a trial?

Comment: @JemCelespara Get [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/solutions/ltspice). Totally free. No broken versions, either. Just works. However, it does have a "reduced library." (The expensive brands make an effort to provide much more complete libraries handy.) But there's plenty of user support here and the manufacturers also provide models that are easy to include. Yes, you will need to learn to use new software. And that takes time.

Comment: @JemCelespara I've added some new stuff for you to consider.

Comment: Thanks!! Btw, I did realized that I had an error in multiplying LCD equation in Node 3, which gave me wrong answers.

Comment: @JemCelespara Great! Regardless of how, I'm glad you are getting correct answers now. Best wishes!

Comment: I downloaded LTSpice but it appears to crash very often whenever I click the accept button in its EULA.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my calculations

$$ 10 = (V_1 - V_3)/2 + ( V_1 - V_2)/3  $$ @Node 1

$$ (V_2 - 0)/4 = (V_1 - V_3)/2 + 4( V_2 - 0)/4  $$ @Node 2

$$ (V_1 - V_3)/2 = (V_2 - 0)/4 + ( V_3 - 0)/6  $$ @Node 3

Applying simplification

$$ 5V_1 - 2V_2 - 3V_3 = 60  $$ (1)
$$ 4V_1  + 5V_2 = 0 $$ (2)
$$ 3V_1 - 6V_2 - 4V_3 = 0 $$ (3)

Solving with calculator: 
$$ V_1 = 80 Volts $$
$$ V_2 = -64 Volts $$
$$ V_3 = 156 Volts $$

This has been edited. I realized that there is an error in node 3. I multiplied both sides by 12 without me knowing that the LCD is 6 rather than 12. I now have the correct answer.